# Openflow Swicth not pushing MPLS tag. (OpenDayLight)

Tags: sdn, opendaylight

I have the following linear SDN architecture with an ODL controller:

```
Host1 -- ZodiacFX1 -- ZodiacFX2 --- Host2
```

I am using 2 laptops as hosts and 2 ZodiacFX openflow switches.

I Want the ZodiacFX1 to push a MPLS tag to all the IP packets received from Host1 and the ZodiacFX2 to pop the MPLS tag and send the IP packets to the Host2.

I have added a flow for the MPLS push on the ZodiacFX1 and I can see the flow active in the ZodiacFX1 and also in the operational datastore of ODL. But if I ping h1->h2 there is no push.

The flow is this:

NOTE:(Host1 is conected to port 1 of ZodiacFX1 and ZodiacFX1 port2 is conected to ZodiacFX2 port1.)

```
 GET  http://192.168.21.147:8181/restconf/operational/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node/openflow:123917682137538/table/2

{
"flow-node-inventory:table": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "opendaylight-flow-table-statistics:flow-table-statistics": {
            "active-flows": 1,
            "packets-looked-up": 0,
            "packets-matched": 0
        },
        "flow": [
            {
                "id": "125",
                "idle-timeout": 0,
                "cookie": 401,
                "flags": "",
                "hard-timeout": 0,
                "instructions": {
                    "instruction": [
                        {
                            "order": 0,
                            "apply-actions": {
                                "action": [
                                    {
                                        "order": 2,
                                        "output-action": {
                                            "output-node-connector": "2",
                                            "max-length": 0
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "order": 1,
                                        "set-field": {
                                            "protocol-match-fields": {
                                                "mpls-label": 27
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "order": 0,
                                        "push-mpls-action": {
                                            "ethernet-type": 34887
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "cookie_mask": 0,
                "opendaylight-flow-statistics:flow-statistics": {
                    "duration": {
                        "nanosecond": 0,
                        "second": 7
                    },
                    "byte-count": 0,
                    "packet-count": 0
                },
                "priority": 0,
                "table_id": 2,
                "match": {
                    "in-port": "1",
                    "ethernet-match": {
                        "ethernet-type": {
                            "type": 2048
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "124",
                "idle-timeout": 0,
                "cookie": 401,
                "flags": "",
                "hard-timeout": 0,
                "instructions": {
                    "instruction": [
                        {
                            "order": 0,
                            "apply-actions": {
                                "action": [
                                    {
                                        "order": 2,
                                        "output-action": {
                                            "output-node-connector": "2",
                                            "max-length": 0
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "order": 1,
                                        "set-field": {
                                            "protocol-match-fields": {
                                                "mpls-label": 27
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "order": 0,
                                        "push-mpls-action": {
                                            "ethernet-type": 34887
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "cookie_mask": 0,
                "opendaylight-flow-statistics:flow-statistics": {
                    "duration": {
                        "nanosecond": 0,
                        "second": 180
                    },
                    "byte-count": 0,
                    "packet-count": 0
                },
                "priority": 8,
                "table_id": 2,
                "match": {
                    "in-port": "1",
                    "ethernet-match": {
                        "ethernet-type": {
                            "type": 2048
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

And I can see too in Zodiac console interface:

```
Flow 6
 Match:
  In Port: 1
  ETH Type: IPv4
 Attributes:
  Table ID: 2                           Cookie:0x191
  Priority: 8                           Duration: 247 secs
 Hard Timeout: 0 secs                  Idle Timeout: 0 secs
  Byte Count: 0                 Packet Count: 0
  Last Match: 00:04:07
  Instructions:
  Apply Actions:
   Push MPLS tag
   Set MPLS Label: 27
   Output Port: 2
```

What can be the problem? I think that the main problem is that in this case Zodiac is following this flow, I have tried my flow with priority 0 too and there is no MPLS push.

```
Flow 5
Match:
In Port: 1
 Attributes:
 Table ID: 0                           Cookie:0x2b00000000000008
 Priority: 2                           Duration: 2845 secs
 Hard Timeout: 0 secs                  Idle Timeout: 0 secs
 Byte Count: 576265                    Packet Count: 5246
 Last Match: 00:00:00
Instructions:
 Apply Actions:
Output Port: 3
Output Port: 2
Output: CONTROLLER
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you have some other application (maybe it's l2switch) pushing
flows to your switches as well. Maybe just install openflowplugin and try.

also, try putting your mpls flows in table 0 instead of table 2.